# Update fields of array subdocuments with one request

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document in a collection:

```
{
    _id: 'test',
    values: [
        { foo: 1, bar: [<very big array>] },
        { foo: 4, bar: [<very big array>] },
        { foo: 3, bar: [<very big array>] }
    ]
}
```

I want to update all `values[].foo` values at once with a pre-calculated array. For performances reasons, I don't want to read the `values[].bar` arrays and since `values` can contains many elements, I'm searching a way to do it with only one request (if possible).

For example, I want to write something like this:

```
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: 'test' }, { $set: { 'values[].foo': [2, 3, 4] }});
```

And the result would be the following:

```
{
    _id: 'test',
    values: [
        { foo: 2, bar: [<very big array>] },
        { foo: 3, bar: [<very big array>] },
        { foo: 4, bar: [<very big array>] }
    ]
}
```

But I don't know how i must write my update request.

I'm using MongoDB 4.0 and i don't have access to 4.2 features.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB version 4.2 or above? If so, I'd recommend using `$function` for this.

Comment: @Rfroes87 I edited my question. I'm using MongoDB 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v4.2 you can benefit from [updates with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

It gives you ability to calculate new array using [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/index.html) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html):

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {_id: "test"},
    [{$set: {
      values: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                "$values.bar",
                [2,3,4]
              ]
            }
          },
          as: "item",
          in: {
            foo: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$$item",
                1
              ]
            },
            bar: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$$item",
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }}]
)
```

Be sure size of `values` is the same as size of update array.